# How to minify/format with Less and Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, less

I am using grunt to compress my LESS files and I have partial success it's either in one line from the setting compress: true or it's not compressed from false and the optimization value set.

What I would like is one per line class without the comments.

```css
.cssitem {stuff;}
.cssitem {stuff;}
.cssitem {stuff;}
```

My grunt file looks like this:

```css
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
    less: {
      development: {
        options: {
          compress: false,
          yuicompress: true,
          optimization: 2
        },
        files: {
          "css/style.css": "less/style.less" // destination file and source file
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      styles: {
        files: ['less/**/*.less'], // which files to watch
        tasks: ['less'],
        options: {
          nospawn: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'watch']);
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
};
```

Comment: `compress` option is deprecated about a year ago. Yet `yuicompress` and `optimization` options are removed more than three years ago. To minimize your output CSS use specialized tools/plugins (e.g. [`grunt-contrib-cssmin`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin)).

Comment: For a special custom formatting see also [`css-comb`](https://github.com/csscomb/csscomb.js) (and the corresponding grunt [plugin](https://github.com/csscomb/grunt-csscomb)).